# How to convert binary string to normal string in php

Tags: php, string, laravel, encoding, utf-8

**Description of the problem**

I am trying to import email content into a database table. Sometimes, I get an SQL error while inserting a message. I found that it fails when the message content is a binary string instead of a string.
For exemple, I get this in the console if I print a message that is imported successfully (Truncated)
[image: Console output when successfully imported]

However, I get this with problematic import:
[image: Console output when cannot import]

I found out that if I use the function `utf8_encode`, I am successfully able to import it into SQL. The problem is that it "breaks" previously successfull imports accented characters:
[image: Broken accented caracters]

**What I have tried**

- Detect if the string was a binary string with `ctype_print`, returned false for both non binary and binary string. I would have then be able to call `utf8_encode` only if it was binary
- Use of `unpack`, did not work
- Detect string encoding with `mb_detect_encoding`, return `UTF-8` for both
- use `iconv` , failed with `iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string`
- Cast the content as string using `(string)` / `settype($html, 'string')`

**Question**
How can I transform the binary string in a normal string so I can then import it in my database without breaking accented characters in other imports?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: What is the charset/collation set on your database? What database are you using? Where is your actual code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: I can't change the database charset|collation. The collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS and I am using sql server

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty late, but for anyone else reading... Apparently the `b` prefix is meaningless in PHP, it's a bit of a red herring. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51537602/6111743

What encodings did you pass to `iconv()`? This is the correct solution but you have to give it the correct first argument, which depends on your input. In my example I use `"LATIN1"` because that turned out to be the correct way to interpret my input but your use case may vary.

You can use `mb_check_encoding()` to check if it is valid UTF-8 or not. This returns a boolean.

Assuming the question is really something like "how to convert extended ascii string to valid utf-8 string in PHP" - Here is how I did it in my application:

```
if(!mb_check_encoding($string)) {
    $string = iconv("LATIN1", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", $string);
}
```

The "TRANSLIT" part tells it to attempt transliteration, that's optional for you. The "IGNORE" will prevent it from throwing `Detected an illegal character in input string` if it does detect one; instead the character will just get ignored, meaning, removed. Your use case may not need either of these.

When you're debugging, I recommend just using "UTF-8" as the second argument so you can see what it's doing. It's useful to see if it throws an error. For me, I had given it the wrong first argument at first (I wrote "ASCII" instead of "LATIN-1") and it threw the illegal character error on an accented character. That error went away once I passed it the correct encoding.

By the way, `mb_detect_encoding()` was no help to me in figuring out that Latin-1 was what I needed. What helped was dumping the contents of `unpack("C*", $string)` to see what exact bytes were in there. That's more debugging advice than solution but worth mentioning in case it helps.